# Extending core Laravel 4 component class?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'd like to tweak the Illuminate\Html\FormBuilder class in Laravel 4 to automatically include a CSS class with each input, corresponding to the type of input, e.g. <input type="radio" class="radio" />

I've created my own class, which extends the original:

```
namespace Shady;

class FormBuilder extends Illuminate\Html\FormBuilder {

    public function input($type, $name, $value = null, $options = array()) {
        $options['class'] = isset($options['class'])
                ? implode(' ', array_unique(array_merge(array($type), explode(' ', $options['class']))))
                : $type;

        parent::input($type, $name, $value, $options);
    }
}
```

Now, the question is, how do I get Laravel 4 to use it?

I've had a look in app/config/app.php, and there's only a reference to the HTML Fascade class. I'm not sure how or where that translates into the Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider\HtmlServiceProvider class, but that class hard-codes the FormBuilder class, ala

```
protected function registerFormBuilder()
{
    $this->app['form'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
    {
        $form = new FormBuilder($app['html'], $app['url'], $app['session']->getToken());

        return $form->setSessionStore($app['session']);
    });
}
```

I'm wondering whether I can either trick it into loading my version of the class somehow? Or if not, how else do I add in this functionality smoothly and neatly? Cheers.

Comment: It seems like a lot of extra work just to get this to work, when you could easily use CSS selectors to find these types of inputs. Is it *really* necessary?

Comment: In this case, I am an idiot and didn't realise CSS selectors could do that (that's what happens when you step out of development for 18 months). But as a principle I'd like to know how it's done so I can do it for other things too. Cheers

Comment: At that level in the framework, I don't think you'd want to override any of the methods. Instead, use `HTML::macro()` to define your own method. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There's a new section in the docs about extending Laravel that should help: http://laravel.com/docs/extending

Comment: I don't see anything on that page about Forms.

Comment: @iconoclast The question wasn't really about forms.

Answer (score 1):

I also tried battling this issue as I wanted to do exactly the same as you, partly out of interest of extending core classes but also to stop repeating myself (DRY) from passing the same two classes in the second (options) array parameter each time I wanted a submit button, but to no avail.

Instead, I opted in the end to make a HTML macro, as others suggested above but here's an actual example for others who might come across this.

**Example:**

Save the following code to `app/macros.php` (this file doesn't exist by default so create it):

```
HTML::macro( 'submit', function( $value = null, $options = array() )
{
    $options = array_merge( $options, array( 'class' => 'btn btn-info' ) );
    return Form::input( 'submit', null, $value, $options );
});
```

Now include macros.php by adding `require app_path().'/macros.php';` to the bottom of `app/start/global.php`.

And now in your views, instead of:

```
Form::submit( 'Submit', array( 'class' => 'btn btn-info' ) );
```

Use:

```
HTML::submit( 'Submit' );
```

And it will produce the same submit button, allowing the same parameters as Laravel by default but will automatically add `btn` and `btn-info` classes to the button, without you needing to repeat yourself each time. Hope this helps someone. =)

Comment: I would have preferred to continue to use `Form::submit(...)` as opposed to having to remember to use `HTML::` so if anyone has a better suggestion, I'm all ears. =)

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22884764/laravel-extend-form-class

Answer (score 0):

It's unnecessary to extend the `HTML` helper class. Instead, use CSS selectors to pick the elements.

As for making your own methods, you can use the `HTML::macro()`

See: http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Html.HtmlBuilder.html#32

And: http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Html.HtmlBuilder.html#390

Comment: I don't feel creating a macro is the right solution, because it doesn't solve the original issue, and gets around it in a very clumsy way. All of my calls to each element (e.g. Form::radio, Form::whatever) have to be changed to route through the macro, and it doesn't promote code reuse.