# Laravel extend Form class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, extend

I'm trying to extend the `Form` class in L4.1 but I seem to be missing something. My file is named `FormBuilder.php` based on the API and is saved in **app/libraries/extended/FormBuilder.php**.

```
<?php namespace Extended;

class FormBuilder extends \Illuminate\Html\FormBuilder {

/**
 * Create a text input field.
 *
 * @param  string  $name
 * @param  string  $value
 * @param  array   $options
 * @return string
 */
public function text($name, $value = null, $options = array())
{
        $options = $options + array('id'=>"field-{$name}");
        return $this->input('text', $name, $value, $options);
}

}
```

This is actually the first time I've tried extending a core class in Laravel. I can't seem to put my finger on how to properly extend core classes like this `Form` class.

**Edit:**
I added `"app/libraries/extended"` to my *composer.json* file and ran both `composer.phar update` and `composer.phar dump-autoload` but it still seemed to be using the core class instead of my extended one. What am I forgetting to do?

Comment: What is the text of the Error 500 page?

Comment: It's a custom 500 page. Let me check if I can.

Comment: Also, verify both the webserver and the Laravel logs, just in case.

Comment: I assume that you've closed your class correctly? It's just not in the above code...

Comment: I see the 500 was for another error which I fixed. I edited the post to remove mentioning any instance of an error 500. The sample page I'm using loads fine but it still seems to be using the core `Form` class and not the extended one.

Comment: How have you registered your new FormBuilder class? You need to register it to be used with the `Form` facade like it is done in the [`HtmlServiceProvider`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Html/HtmlServiceProvider.php#L46)

Comment: @MarcelGwerder please create a proper answer so in case you're right I can mark it as so and give you the mojos you deserve. :)

Comment: I'm working on it im also not 100% sure to write it without testing :P

Comment: Hmm thought I could just override the binding but couldn't get it to work... The right answer is allready there although a bit more work to do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To extend/swap a Laravel core class, you can create a Service Provider:

File: `app/App/Libraries/Extensions/FormBuilder/FormBuilderServiceProvider.php`

```
<?php namespace App\Libraries\Extensions\FormBuilder;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider as  IlluminateServiceProvider;
use App\Libraries\Extensions\FormBuilder\FormBuilder;

class FormBuilderServiceProvider extends IlluminateServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Indicates if loading of the provider is deferred.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $defer = true;

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bindShared('formbuilder', function($app)
        {
            $form = new FormBuilder($app['html'], $app['url'], $app['session.store']->getToken());

            return $form->setSessionStore($app['session.store']);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Get the services provided by the provider.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function provides()
    {
        return array('formbuilder');
    }

}
```

Create a Facade for it:

File: `app/App/Libraries/Extensions/FormBuilder/FormBuilderFacade.php`

```
<?php namespace App\Libraries\Extensions\FormBuilder;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade as IlluminateFacade;

class FormBuilderFacade extends IlluminateFacade {

    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'formbuilder'; }

}
```

This would be your namespaced service class:

File: `app/App/Libraries/Extensions/FormBuilder/FormBuilder.php`

```
<?php namespace App\Libraries\Extensions\FormBuilder;

use \Illuminate\Html\FormBuilder as IlluminateFormBuilder;

class FormBuilder extends IlluminateFormBuilder {

    public function text($name, $value = null, $options = array())
    {
        $options = $options + array('id'=>"field-{$name}");

        return $this->input('text', $name, $value, $options);
    }

}
```

Open `app/config/app.php` and your Service Provider to the list

```
'App\Libraries\Extensions\FormBuilder\FormBuilderServiceProvider',
```

And replace Laravel's Form alias with yours

```
    'Form'            => 'App\Libraries\Extensions\FormBuilder\FormBuilderFacade',
```

To test I created a router like this:

```
Route::any('test', function() {

   return e(Form::text('first_name'));

});
```

And it gave me this result:

```
<input id="field-first_name" name="first_name" type="text">
```

Comment: No `namespace` required anywhere?

Comment: Namespace is up to you, but you better namespace it all.

Comment: This worked great for my requirements. The only problem is it works if the files are in the __Libraries__ folder (`namespace App\Libraries`) but not in the __Extensions__ subfolder (`namespace App\Libraries\Extensions`).

Comment: I hear Laravel has 2 ways of extending core classes. For the record, which one is this?

Comment: YOu just have to rename the namespaces and they should work. I just renamed them all in the answer. About the other extensions, actually there are more than one way of doing this. But in the docs you'll that some classes have an `extend()` method, but it's not the FormBuilder case, so it wouldn't work for it, look:http://laravel.com/docs/extending. In FormBuilder you can create Macros, but this is not really an extension because you cannot just rewrite core methods.

Comment: In your __composer.json__ file what did you type in the __classmap__ section?

Comment: I assume you would need "app/App" in the classmap array based on his folder structure above.