# How to extend the MessageBag class in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I need to edit the [add](http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Support/MessageBag.html#method_add) method in `Laravel 4 MessageBag` class.

How can I extend it in my laravel app and register to use `MyMessageBag` class instead of the default `MessageBag` class.

```
use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;

class MyMessageBag extends MessageBag {


   public function add($key, $message)
    {
        if ($this->isUnique($key, $message))
        {
            $this->messages[$key] = $message;
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this? http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/extending

Anyway, I think you can extend Laravel core classes by following these steps:

- Create and register a service provider
- Add a facade for that service provider, to allow you using static methods, and replace the alias to your custom namespaced class

Maybe this answers your question (with code): [Laravel extend Form class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22884764/laravel-extend-form-class)

Comment: but. messagebag is  not a core class used by laravel