# Laravel selectRange/selectMonth 2 digits

Tags: php, forms, laravel

Okay, I have a laravel form with selectRange/selectMonth inputs in, but how can I make it so all of them are 2 digits long?

So, for my first selectRange from 1-31, all the one digit numbers would be like: 01, 02, 03, 04, etc.

And my month one would be the same, but with the 1-12 numbers.

```
{{ Form::label('day', 'What\'s your date of birth?') }}
{{ Form::selectRange('day', 01, 31, null, array('class' => 'date')) }}
{{ Form::selectMonth('month', null, array('class' => 'month')) }}
{{ Form::selectRange('year', 2014, 1880, null, array('class' => 'year')) }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use `Form::select` instead of `Form::selectRange` in such case. Example:

**For Days:**

```
$days = [];
for($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++){
    $val = ($i < 10) ? '0'.$i : $i;
    $days[$val] = $val;
}
Form::select('day', $days, '01');
```

**For months:**

```
$months = [
    '01' => 'January',
    '02' => 'February',
    '03' => 'March',
    '04' => 'April',
    '05' => 'May',
    '06' => 'June',
    '07' => 'July',
    '08' => 'August',
    '09' => 'September',
    '10' => 'October',
    '11' => 'November',
    '12' => 'December'
];

Form::select('month', $months, '01');
```

Comment: Eugh, how can I work this in with the month though? That has a value of 1-12 but the text is the name of the month?

Comment: Manually generate month array and pass it as I updated!

Answer (score 0):

`Form::selectRange` doesn't support leading zeros. So you will have to build the options yourself and use the normal `Form::select` (like void main's answer says)
Best practice would be to write a reusable range function with leading zeros.

```
public function selectRangeLeadingZeros($name, $begin, $end, $selected = null, $options = array()){
    $range = array_combine($range = range($begin, $end), $range);
    foreach($range as &$value){
        $value = str_pad($value, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
    return Form::select($name, $range, $selected, $options);
}
```

This is basically the content of the `selectRange` method with an added foreach loop to put the leading zeros in there.

You can put this in a custom helper class / file or [extend the Laravel form class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22884764/laravel-extend-form-class)

And you would use it the same as you do now with `selectRange`

Comment: Where the heck should I put this?

Comment: @TomDoyle I probably misunderstood your question. Or I rather answered before you posted your code. I'll take a look and update my answer...

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel 5** - Laravel Collective HTML

It is actually simple to do month and year:

```
{!! Form::selectMonth('month', null, ['class'=>'month']) !!}
{!! Form::selectYear('year', date('Y'), date('Y')-100, null, ['class'=>'year']) !!}
```

As for Day I would just do something similar to @mehedi-pstu-2K9's answer.

You can also easily add formatting. For month just pass the [format string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) as the fourth parameter. Say you are getting credit card info and want it 0-padded:

```
{!! Form::selectMonth('month', null, ['class'=>'month'], '%m') !!}
```

As for Year, we are already passing a format string. Just change both instances of `date('Y')` to `date('y')` (lower y) and it will be two digits.