# Glyphicon in Html::link using MaterializeCss

Tags: laravel, materialize

How should I parse this link to laravel so it will have a glyphicon to hold my navbar links when I use a mobile device?

```html
<a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
```

I'm using Laravel 4.2 and [Materializecss](http://materializecss.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do this using illuminate/html, here's explanation:

```blade
{{ 
    HTML::link(
        '#', 
        /* here's the issue, described below */, 
        array(
            'class' => 'button-collapse',
            'data-activates' => 'mobile-demo',
        )
    ) 
}}
```

As you can see [in source](https://github.com/illuminate/html/blob/3d1009bb8e0f25720c914af5c1f4015dd373c9ef/HtmlBuilder.php#L115) you can't provide HTML inside generated link, as it will be encoded with [htmlentities](https://php.net/htmlentities).

Comment: @FerchoCarcho yes, here's quick guide: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22885148/1331425

Comment: glad to help, if you're happy with my answer you can accept it.